# Custom record identifier using alfresco record management

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Presently in alfresco records management Unique identifier is numeric number.
 Need to  customize the unique identifier to support alpha numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I does support alpha numeric:

```
<property name="rma:identifier">
               <title>Record Component Identifier</title>
               <type>d:text</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
               <index enabled="true">
                  <atomic>true</atomic>
                  <stored>false</stored>
                  <tokenised>false</tokenised>
               </index>
            </property>
```

So you can update this property, create your own behaviour or extend the java class **org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_rm.identifier.BasicIdentifierGenerator**
to define your own identifier.